Pine Script Array Issues - Drawing Boxes
I'm making a pine script code that draws out the last 3 demand zones based off the candle closes etc. The script draws the boxes correctly however im trying to figure out how to remove the box once price crosses back through and also have it display the previous zones before it instead of just deleting the zone once it crosses.
Any ideas for my script would be epic!
I tried deleting them but it would only leave me with 2 boxes instead of rolling back to show the previous 3 zones:
See my Code below:
//@version=5
indicator('Cams Supply and Demand Test', overlay=true, max_labels_count=500, max_boxes_count=500)
// 0.1

//Variable Creation

var box [] Boxes = array.new_box(3)


[H,L,C,O] = request.security(syminfo.ticker, "240", [high[0],low[0], close[0], open[0]],         lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
DemandZone =  ((C[1] < O[1]) and C > H[1])
DemandCPrice = ta.valuewhen(DemandZone, L[1], 0)
DemandCPriceHigh = ta.valuewhen(DemandZone, H[1], 0)
DemandZoneRL = ((C[1] < O[1]) and C > H[1])
DemandCPriceRL = ta.valuewhen(DemandZoneRL, L[1], 0)
DemandCPriceHighRL = ta.valuewhen(DemandZoneRL, H[1], 0)

if (DemandZoneRL)
array.push(Boxes, box.new(bar_index , DemandCPriceHigh, bar_index[1], DemandCPrice, extend =    extend.right))

if array.size(Boxes) > 3
box.delete(array.shift(Boxes))

//if low < DemandCPriceRL
//    box.delete(array.shift(Boxes))

